# Why can user still input umgc in password and it not come back as false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code, when running it and inputting umgc it will accept the password. Can someone help with why? Thank you so much!

```
def strong_password(password):
Symbol=['#']
umgc=['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
returned=True
if len(password) <= 6:
    print('the length of password should be at least 6 characters long')
    returned=False
if len(password) >= 12:
    print('the length of password should be not be greater than 12')
    returned=False
if not any(char in Symbol for char in password):
    print('the password should have the # symbol')
    returned=False
if password[0] == '#':
    print('The # symbol should not be in the beginning of the password')
    returned=False
if password[-1] == '#':
    print('The password must not end with the # symbol')
    returned=False
if any(char in umgc for char in password):
    print('Password must not contain "UMGC" in any combination of upper/lowercase letters')
    returned=False
if returned:
    print('Strong Password!')
return returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set for membership tests.

Change

```
if any(char in umgc for char in password):
```

to

```
umgc = set('umgc')
if umgc.issubset(password.lower()):
```

---

Your original failed because you are asking if a single character is in a list of *words*.  Your original does this:

```
>>> umgc=['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
>>> password = 'Umgc'     
>>> for char in password:
...     print(f'is {char} in {umgc}') 
...
is U in ['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
is m in ['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
is g in ['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
is c in ['umgc', 'umgC', 'umGc', 'umGC', 'uMgc', 'uMgC', 'uMGc', 'uMGC', 'Umgc', 'UmgC', 'UmGc', 'UmGC', 'UMgc', 'UMgC', 'UMGc', 'UMGC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputting `"umgc"` will accept the password because in this line:

```
if any(char in umgc for char in password):
```

you are asking if there is any char in the password(**word**) that is in the **list of words** `umgc`:

This would work however:

```
if any(char in words for words in umgc for char in password):
```

Here we are asking if there is any char in the password matching any of the chars of any word in the list of words.

A better solution is already in the answers.
Hope I could help